# mysql check two tables for results?

Tags: php, mysql

I am using the MySQL query to check 2 tables for any results which are less than 30 days old.

I have table 1 'supplier bank details' and table 2 'supplier invoices'

What I am trying to do is if a result is found from table 1 then  echo out the type of result it is i.e.

```
Result from Table 1           echo{some data from table}      echo{some data from table}
```

or otherwise if the result is from table 2 echo out the following:

```
Result from Table 2           echo{some data from table}      echo{some data from table}
```

otherwise if a result is found in both echo out both however many times the result occurs in table 1 and table 2

i.e:

```
 Result from Table 1           echo{some data from table}      echo{some data from table}
  Result from Table 2           echo{some data from table}      echo{some data from table}
  Result from Table 1          echo{some data from table}      echo{some data from table}
  Result from Table 1           echo{some data from table}      echo{some data from table}
  Result from Table 2           echo{some data from table}      echo{some data from table}
```

and am trying to organise these by date. and otherwise if no results were found to display no results found. My problem is its not working and no results are displayed and neither does it echo my no results found. here is my code, please can someone show me where I am going wrong, thanks

```
<?php require_once 'config.php'; ?>

<?php
$tbl_name1 = 'supplier_bank_details';
$tbl_name2 = 'supplier_invoices';
$query3 = "select * from $tbl_name2 as $tbl_name2, $tbl_name1 as $tbl_name1 WHERE $tbl_name2.date > NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY AND $tbl_name1.date > NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY AND $tbl_name2.user_id = '{$_SESSION['id']}' AND $tbl_name1.user_id = '{$_SESSION['id']}' GROUP BY $tbl_name2.user_id ORDER BY $tbl_name2.date AND  $tbl_name1.date DESC";
$result3 = mysql_query($query3) or die( mysql_error() );
while($row3 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result3)){


$datetime1 = new DateTime(); // Today's Date/Time
$datetime2 = new DateTime($row3['date']);
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);

$s = $interval->format('%d days ago');

if($s === '0 days ago') {
$z = 'amended today';
}else{
$z = 'amended about '.$s.'';
}


$account_number = '****'.substr($row3['account_number'], -4);

if(mysql_num_rows($result3) > 0) {

 // your unique column for Bank Details
            if( !is_null($row3['sort_code'])) {

echo '<div class="contracts_area"><div class="table_header"></div>';
echo '<div class="request"><p>result from table 1</p><p>'.$row3['sort_code'].'</p><p>'.$account_number.'</p><p>'.$z.'</p></div>';
echo '</div>';


            }
            // your unique column for Invoice Details
            if( !is_null($row3['reference'])) { 

                echo '<div class="contracts_area"><div class="table_header"></div>';
echo '<div class="request"><p>result from table 2</p><p>'.$row3['reference'].'</p><p>'.$row3['status'].'</p><p>'.$z.'</p></div>';
echo '</div>';
            }

        }else{

            echo 'No Recent Activity';
        }
        } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that in your query, you aren't asking for "rows from table 1, or rows from table 2" that independently meet the condition. You are asking for "rows from table 1 along with matching rows from table 2" that each meet the same criteria (they have matching IDs).

What you probably want is something more like a [UNION](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp). This essentially takes two different queries (rows from table1 that meet a criteria and rows from table2 that meet a criteria) and puts them together as one unified list of results.

You don't specify your schema to be sure it works, but the query might look something like

```
SELECT * from $tbl1_name where date > NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY and user_id = '{$_SESSION['id']}'
UNION
SELECT * from $tbl2_name where date > NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY and user_id = '{$_SESSION['id']}'
ORDER BY date DESC;
```

Keep in mind that this will now change which columns exist. Again, you don't give us the schema, but while before you would have columns from table 2 followed by columns from table 1, all in the same row, now you'll have the rows following rows, all of which using the same columns. So you will need to adjust later evaluations to handle this.

Comment: thanks for this suggestion, however this gives me an error: uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'DateTime::_construct()

Comment: ok so I have removed the datetime interval code which was causing the initial error, however now I am getting a error saying index reference is undefined for the following line if( !is_null($row3['reference'] )) {

Comment: You may no longer have the column you're trying to find. Answer updated.